# Where can I find performance benchmarks of ALIX.1D system (AMD Geode LX800)

Tags: embedded, benchmarking

The AMD Geode LX800 processor was popular a few years ago, but now I can't find any information related to performance. If anyone has some good links on this, I would love to have them. This processor was also used in the OLPC project.

I am targeting a standard Linux headless install for the system. The specific benchmarks I am interested in are photo manipulation (cropping, resizing, stitching) and MPEG4 encoding. For the video encoding, I need to encode a 60s 30fps 640x480 video. I would like the encoder to finish the encoding withing 1-hour.

Comment: Which exact part do you need benchmark info for? (Regardless of synthetic benchmarks beeing of mostly esoteric "value".) Which OS are you intending to run, this may heavily impact performance, especially in the crypto and networking area.

I'm running multiple ALIX 3D3, 3D13, 3D2, 3D3 boards as routers, tor anonymizer nodes. What is your intended goal to do with this system? Maybe I can then give you a hint if it may be suitable or not.

Comment: ALIX boards don't have any hardware accelleration for MPEG en-/decoding, so everything has be calculated by the CPU. If you can give me an exact example of what you need to do I can test that for you. You'd need to provide a source movie, settings, which packages to apt-get etc. I'm not that familiar with Debian, but If you can give me what you need tested so I can do it with as little effort as possible, I'll be happy to test for you.

Comment: Thanks MacLemon. I bought one anyway, so you don't have to help me out any further. When I get my system running I'll post some information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the x264 Benchmark video compression test from [ApeBox](http://www.apebox.org/wordpress/linux/32/). The test system was running Ubuntu 9.10 2.6.31-20-generic kernel.  You can find more comparison results [here](http://www.techarp.com/showarticle.aspx?artno=442).

```
Pass 1: 3.07 FPS, 1855 kb/s
Pass 2: 0.66 FPS, 1825 kb/s
```